# How do I sort a Perl hash by keys numerically?

Tags: sorting, perl, hash

My first question ... I have found many answers to other questions through search but I am failing to do so this time :-)

I want to generate a report that is sorted by a number that is embedded in a string from my input data. The report is being generate from elements of a perl hash where the same number is used as the hash key.

The output that I am currently getting is sorted like strings.

```
foreach my $num (sort keys %dir_map) {
    $path = $paths{$num};
    $name = $names{$num};
    printf OUT ("%d %s %s\n",$num,$path,$name);
}
```

My input data looks like:

```
dist_14 randomString nameStringIwant RandomInteger AnotherRandomString
```

Which I am processing like:

```
while(<IN>) {
    chomp;
    my @header = split /\s+/;
    my $header_length = $#header ;
    if ( /dist_/ ) {
        my $NumberStr = $header[0] ;
        $justNumberStr =~ s/dist_//;
        my $justNumber = sprintf("%d",$justNumberStr);
        $names{$justNumber} = $header[2];
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean just to sort those keys numerically, as in `(sort { $a <=> $b } keys %dir_map)` ...?  The `sort` by default uses lexicographical sorting, `sort { $a cmp $b } @ary`.

Comment: (in my first comment above, it needn't be an array, but any list ... can't edit anymore :(

Comment: Thank you and, yes, I just want to sort those keys numerically. The input file snippet shown is a string from lines in a file. Looks like a missed a switch of $distDirNumberStr to $justNumberStr in my edits - I will fix that in the original question. My actual printf usage includes formatted floating point values that are derived from a different input file (omitted for simplifciation of the question).

Comment: "_I just want to sort those keys numerically_"  -- OK, then my first comment answers it, yes?  I'd still suggest to clarify the rest (at least some of what I ask in the other comment), as someone may come along and post an answer, also cleaning up and improving that code that populates the hash.

Comment: My first draft of the code used $justNumberStr as the hash key. The sprintf was an attempt to see if I could fix my sort issue by creating a new variable $justNumber that I hoped would be cast as an integer. Neither approach achieved the goal of sorting the output numerically based on the hash key.

Comment: Converting a string-with-a-number to a number mostly happens as needed, but is also a legitimate thing to do just so, I'd say.  But `sort` doesn't make decisions based on what is handed to it; by default is uses [cmp](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Equality-Operators), but then you can tell it in the block what to do. See [sort](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort)

Comment: Thank you. Yes, this solved my problem : (sort { $a <=> $b } keys %dir_map)

Comment: (I deleted a few long comments in the beginning since those questions were clarified by OP's responses.)

Answer (score 2):

As you've discovered, Perl's [sort](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort) will, by default, sort using a string comparison. To override that default behaviour, you need to provide a sort block.

```
foreach my $num (sort { $a <=> $b } keys %dir_map)
```

The sort block is given two of the elements from your list in the variables `$a` and `$b`. Your code should compare these two values and return a negative integer if `$a` comes before `$b`, a positive integer if `$b` comes before `$a` and zero if they sort in the same place. The "spaceship operator" (`<=>`) does exactly that for two numbers.

The FAQ [How do I sort an array by (anything)?](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4#How-do-I-sort-an-array-by-(anything)?)
 might also be useful. You don't have an array, but your list of keys can be treated in the same way.